# Creating a dynamic calculated column using PowerBI DAX

Tags: dynamic, powerbi, calculated-columns

I am new to PowerBI and I am facing a challenge with creating a calculated column that will get updated automatically as the dataset keeps getting filtered. My dataset looks like this -

[image: Dataset Image]

I have created the Deliverable_Milestone_Match column using the formula -

```
Deliverable_Milestone_Match = 
IF(
    Sheet1[Issue_Type] = "CO Deliverable", 
    VAR _sel = SELECTCOLUMNS(
        Sheet1, 
        "MilestoneIssueKey", 
        [Issue_Key]
    ) 
    RETURN 
    IF(
        Sheet1[MilestoneIssueKey] IN _sel, 
        "MAPPED",
        "UNMAPPED"
    ),
    "MILESTONE"
)
```

Now, the challenge is, that I will need to apply some filters to this dataset, and since my calculated column references other columns in the data, it also needs to change accordingly. For example The formula is looking up the presence of MilestoneIssueKey in Issue_Key, and it is populating MAPPED if it gets a match, and UNMAPPED otherwise. Now, if I apply a filter that removes a specific unique Issue_Key, then the corresponding MilestoneIssueKey won't have a match anymore, and the Deliverable_Milestone_Match value should change to UNMAPPED now.

I would appreciate it if anyone can help me with this. I am not even sure if this can be achieved via DAX or whether I will need to use Power Query for this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide your table and dummy data as a markdown table so that it can be easily copy/pasted by the answerer

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow

Answer (score 0):

You first issue is the following:

> [...] calculated column that **will get updated automatically as the dataset keeps getting filtered**

Calculated columns aren't refreshed dynamicaly as filter context evolves. As explained [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/power-bi-calculated-measures-vs-calculated-columns-9be012e9bff1) :

> Since calculated columns live at the same level as your tables, they are only calculated when you first define them and during a dataset refresh.

So, in that regard you should try to solve your problem using Measures.